# Feature importance has more variables than included in .csv?

Tags: feature-selection, xgboost

I have a .csv dataset with 26 variables, ranging from Age to Weight and so forth. I plotted a feature importance plot with;

```
model.get_booster().feature_names
xgb.plot_importance(model)
```

However, it's giving me a range of variables from f0, f1, f2, ... f26. Meaning there's one extra variable included for some reason. 27 variables.

I cannot get labels/feature names to work correctly, so I can't view what the extra variable is.

Comment: Can you give a sample dataset, and minimal code for fitting, that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the size of input matrix to XGBoost, Its not possible for XGBoost to return more variables then in the input.

```
f0 = refers to variable at 0 index
```

Please share codes and sample data for clear drill down